# Can my Raspberry Pi Zero W python program be duplicated and resold?

Tags: pi-3, python, security

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W that runs a program under the main username, Pi. I'm going to give this Pi to someone for their own use, however I expect them to use the Pi for their application without being able to access the code itself (and potentially replicate). I have two questions:

1- If they tried copying the SD card, it will still ask for the same password right?

2- The Pi is preconfigured to use a specific SSID and Password, copying the SD card will still limit any use of the Pi at another wifi point right? So they would be able to duplicate my Pi but only be use it in the preconfigured wifi details?

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, unless they know how to access the data on the SD card - which is basically anyone with a raspberry pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone has physical access to the SD Card they can do ANYTHING, even if they don't know the password.

Comment: If I convert it into an executable file, will they be able to read the contents and reverse engineer it?

Comment: @NLed Yes - if it is worth their while.